# To allow 0-9,a-z,A-Z and the special characters . , @ & ( ) {} [ ] : ; in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to allow 0-9,a-z,A-Z and the special characters . , @ & ( ) {} [ ] : ; in text     box.

Please help me to write regular expression for that. Currently I have a code that replace none word character with empty data and I want to made changes so that it also allow above special character.

```
function deleteSpecialChar(txtName, event) {

    if (txtName.value != '' && txtName.value.match(/^[\w]+$/) == null) {

        txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/[\W]/g, '');
    };
}
$('input[type=text]').live('keypress keyup keydown cut copy paste', function (event) {

    deleteSpecialChar(this, event);
});
```

Comment: Don't use `live`, use `on`. `live` has been deprecated some time ago

Comment: I find it helps to use something like regexpal or one of it's alternatives that way you can test your expression against likely inputs and this quickly exposes any unexpected results and helps you learn how to construct your expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Just put what you want to remove in a set:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z.,@&(){}\[\]:;]+
```

Use the `test` method, and you can use the same regular expression for the check and the replace, instead of having one positive and one negative:

```
function deleteSpecialChar(txtName, event) {
  var re = /[^0-9,a-z,A-Z\.,@&\(\)\{\}\[\]:;]+/g;
  if (txtName.value != '' && txtName.value.test(re)) {
    txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(re, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: The char class can be simplified to: `[^0-9a-zA-Z.,@&(){}:;\[\]]`, no need to escape all that stuff

Comment: +1 for simplifying the code, one remark. the commas between `0-9,a-z,A-Z` are not needed.

Comment: @NullUserException: Right, I just escaped everything that I wasn't really certain about.

Comment: @stema: Yes, of course, I forgot to remove them when I copied the characters from the text.

Comment: Just remember that only `[]^-` (and the backlash itself) are metacharacters in a char class. Even then you can get away with not escaping them by placing them in strategic places (eg: `[abc-]` is equivalent to `[abc\-]`). There are people who prefer to escape them anyway just to be sure, I personally like to escape as little as possible to keep things clean.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/[^\w.,@&(){}\[\]:;]/g, '');
```

The character class starting with `^` is a negated class, so this will replace every character that is not in that class.

Comment: `\w` includes the underscore though